# I am trying to place markers on a map from an xml file but my map appears without any markers

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my xml code saved as 'phpsqlajax.php'

```
<?php
require("db_connect1.php");
function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&apos;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected=mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1=1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML('&','&amp;', $row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}
// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

I am trying to download this and implement it onto my map which is saved as 'mapxml.html', however the map only displays an image of Seattle and not the markers that I have saved in my database. Here is the mapxml.html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var customIcons = {
          field: {
            icon: 'img/marker.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
          },
          Park: {
            icon: 'img/marker.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
          }
        };
        function load() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
          });
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
          downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("markers");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
              var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
              var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
              var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
              });
              bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
          });
        }
        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        }
        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
              new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
              new XMLHttpRequest;
          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request, request.status);
            }
          };
          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);
        }
        function doNothing() {}
        //]]>
      </script>
      </head>

      <body onload="load()">
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

does anybody know the reason my markers are not displayed?

I have been following the Google tutorial and my XML is outputting fine however I cannot seem to finish the instructions https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried to place a marker with static coords and ignore the xml output for testing?

Comment: What does the XML returned by your AJAX request look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`47.6145, -122.3418` is the coordinates for Seattle.  If you want to see all the markers being returned by your AJAX request, you need to adjust your map's bounds to fit the markers.

Here's an amended version of your for loop to include that:

```js
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))
    );

    bounds.extend(point);

    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```